# WS02 5.0 Integration WS02 IDP

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I tried to integrate WSo2 API with IDP(Postgresql as DB) . I am getting the below exception when I try to generate the production keys

WSo2 IS log

org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.IdentityApplicationManagementException: Error while creating application role: Application/apistore_PizzaShack_PRODUCTION with user apistore
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationMgtUtil.createAppRole(ApplicationMgtUtil.java:145)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationManagementServiceImpl.createApplication(ApplicationManagementServiceImpl.java:129)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyMgtSubscriberService.createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo(APIKeyMgtSubscriberService.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Role name: Application/apistore_PizzaShack_PRODUCTION in the system. Please pick another role name.
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.doAddInternalRole(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:2927)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addRole(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:2506)

WSo2 API logs

and try again.
2016-10-19 07:29:15,312 [-] [HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1]  WARN AccessConfiguration Error loading properties from file: access-log.properties
2016-10-19 07:30:37,473 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-22] ERROR AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl Can not create OAuth application  : PizzaShack1_PRODUCTION
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException: APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.createOAuthA

```
... 75 more
```

2016-10-19 07:30:37,706 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-22] ERROR APIStoreHostObject Error while obtaining the application access token for the application:PizzaShack1
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Could not execute Workflow
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:2815)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIConsumer.requestApprovalForApplicatio

Answer (score 0):

The reason is role name Application/apistore_PizzaShack_PRODUCTION is already in the system.

When you are creating a Service Provider, an associated role will be created.

You can try to add Service Provider after deleting or renaming Application/apistore_PizzaShack_PRODUCTION role.

Thanks
Isura

Comment: Thanks for the response. After integration, These are the steps I did

Comment: Thanks for the response. After integration, These are the steps I did - 1) Created an api and associated it with an newly created application.2) Generated a production key and accessed the api with the newly generated access code. So far so good. After this, I tried to go to the Production key page and I can see an exception there ." Partially created key" and then a Clean Up button. I clicked on the clean up button and the clicked on the Generate production key button . Now I get an exception. Not sure why it worked the first time and failed in the second time